# Асинхроность между двумя дивами на js?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такая структура:

```
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="wrapper1-item active"></div>
  <div class="wrapper1-item"></div>
  <div class="wrapper1-item"></div>
  <div class="wrapper1-item"></div>
  <div class="wrapper1-item"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="wrapper2-item active"></div>
  <div class="wrapper2-item"></div>
  <div class="wrapper2-item"></div>
  <div class="wrapper2-item"></div>
  <div class="wrapper2-item"></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике по элементу из `wrapper1` элемент, который находится в точно такой же позиции по индексу из `wrapper2` получил класс `active`.
А у остальных удалялось, ибо только 2 могут иметь класс `active`

Только чистый `JS` интересует

Answer (score 2):

```js
var wrapper1Item = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper1-item');
var wrapper2Item = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper2-item');
for (let i = 0; i < wrapper1Item.length; i++) {
  wrapper1Item[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < wrapper1Item.length; i++) {
      wrapper1Item[i].classList.remove('active');
      wrapper2Item[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    wrapper1Item[i].classList.add('active');
    wrapper2Item[i].classList.add('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.wrapper1-item.active {
  background: red;
}

.wrapper2-item.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="wrapper1-item active">wrapper1-item</div>
  <div class="wrapper1-item">wrapper1-item</div>
  <div class="wrapper1-item">wrapper1-item</div>
  <div class="wrapper1-item">wrapper1-item</div>
  <div class="wrapper1-item">wrapper1-item</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="wrapper2-item active">wrapper2-item</div>
  <div class="wrapper2-item">wrapper2-item</div>
  <div class="wrapper2-item">wrapper2-item</div>
  <div class="wrapper2-item">wrapper2-item</div>
  <div class="wrapper2-item">wrapper2-item</div>
</div>
```